# SQL Group By Percentage Increments

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, group-by, percentage

I have a table with a list of scores for a test, lets say scores out of 30 for example.

I would like to present the data by counting the number of people who's score was in certain percentage bracket.

For example:

```
Total   % Bracket
-----------------
5       95-100%
15      90-94%   
20      85-89%
17      80-84%
15      75-79%
etc
```

I thought about calculating the score required for each percentage bracket first and then doing a `SUM(CASE ....` somehow, but I seem to have lost my way.

Comment: Can you share an example of expected result?

Comment: @Kuzgun I have it's in the question. I would like a count of the total people in a certain percentage bracket

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Whose SQL? Oracle, Sql Server?

Comment: Sorry it's MSSQL 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not got time to test this but something long the lines of..

```
select t.pcbracket as [% Bracket], count(*) as [NumWithMark]
from (
  select case  
    when mark between 0 and 9 then ' 0- 9'
    when mark between 10 and 19 then '10-19'
    when mark between 20 and 29 then '20-29'
    when mark between 30 and 39 then '30-39'
    else '40-100' end as pcbracket
  from testresults) t
group by t.pcbracket
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track, just has to convert the score into a percentage, then used your method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CASE WHEN but in this case you will miss intervals with 0 count of records. So you can do it in the following way:

```
select t2.start,t2.finish, count(t.score) from t
RIGHT JOIN 
(
select 0 as start, 4 as finish
union all
select 5 as start, 9 as finish
union all
select 10 as start, 14 as finish
union all
.......
union all
select 95 as start, 99 as finish  
) as t2 on t.score between t2.start and t2.finish

group by t2.start,t2.finish
order by  t2.start
```

[Here is SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c22d4/8)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a nested query to resolve this.
Inner query i would use simple group by percentage and then on top of it i would use case to specify percentage ranges and get the output.